# angular ngbtooltip position is affected when the parent div has the display none property

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a parent div which initially has display:none css property and then based on condition, display property is made block.
However, position of the tooltip on its child div is affected and not positioned as expected. If i remove the display property, the tooltip renders properly.

Is there any way to recalculate the tooltip position once the parent div's css property is made display:block

Comment: When you don't have the dynamic CSS and the tooltip is visible, what is the value of the `display` property of the parent?

Comment: use `visibility: hidden / visible` instead of `display: none`

Comment: I cannot use visibility hidden as it takes up space in the DOM. I had already tried this.

Comment: @Antediluvian, i didn't understand your question

Comment: @Maria By what you are saying, I assume you have `<parent [ngClass]="condition ? 'd-none' : 'd-block'"></parent>`. What I meant is if you remove `[ngClass]` and its expression altogether, and at the same time, make your tooltip show up. At this point of time, what is the `display` property of your `parent` tag? My suspicion is that you might need another value for the `display` property instead of `block`, eg. `inline-block`, `flex` etc.